# Android keywords dictionary - spell check - Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, keyword, spell-checking

Is there any Android keywords dictionary (.dic) for Android Studio spell checker?
Such words as `Async`,`listview`,`GZIP`,`gradlew`, etc.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is an [`android.dic`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/org/jetbrains/android/spellchecker/android.dic) by default in IntelliJ12 and Android-Studio :

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/adt/idea/+/master/android/src/org/jetbrains/android/spellchecker/android.dic

But you will be disappointed, it seems it contains only 56 words.

An alternative is to add words manually:

- right click on the word
- spelling > save to dictionary

Comment: Thanks, there is room for improvement and I'll consider pushing a changes to `master` or `upstream-master`.